# Problems passing an ObservableProperty variable via BindableProperty into GraphicsView canvas

Tags: c#, maui, bindableproperty

I am trying to pass a variable into my GraphicsView canvas, but it looks like I have some problems receiving the passed variable in my drawable.

What am I doing wrong?

Drawable

```
public class NewDrawable : IDrawable
{

    public float Vectors { get; set; }

    public static BindableProperty VectorsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Vectors), typeof(float), typeof(NewDrawable));


    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {


        canvas.StrokeColor = Color.FromRgba("ebc500");
        canvas.StrokeSize = 15;
        canvas.StrokeLineCap = LineCap.Round;
        canvas.DrawArc(40, 40, 200, 200, 90, Vectors, true, false);
```

View

```
            <GraphicsView x:Name="newDrawableView">
                <GraphicsView.Drawable>
                    <drawables:NewDrawable Vectors="{Binding TotalProcent}" />
                </GraphicsView.Drawable>
            </GraphicsView>
```

ViewModel

```
        [ObservableProperty]
        public float totalProcent;
```

The variable should be passed to my drawable

Answer (score 0):

Look at code snippet in [Bindable Properties / Create Accessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-7.0#create-accessors).

Property `Vectors`  is missing get/set code that uses `VectorsProperty`, to tell XAML what is happening:

```cs
public float Vectors
{
    get => (float)GetValue(VectorsProperty);
    set => SetValue(VectorsProperty, value);
}
```

---

**To use `GetValue`**

From [Bindable Properties / Create a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-property):

> To create a `BindableProperty` instance, the containing class must derive from the `BindableObject` class. However, the `BindableObject` class is high in the class hierarchy, so the majority of classes used for UI functionality support bindable properties.

Have your custom class inherit from `BindableObject`:

```cs
public class NewDrawable : BindableObject, IDrawable
```

Comment: The `GetValue(VectorsProperty)` should return as `float` instead of `bool`. I have edited it. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried that, but I get this error: The name 'GetValue' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I've added to answer.